# Web Security Proxy using Computer Accounts instead of User Accounts

Tags: proxy, authentication, web, squid

All our internet traffic goes through a web security proxy product, a squid server essentially hosted on one of our servers.

This connects through to the online portal service we pay for which allows or denies access to websites based on rules created by ourselves.

We've noticed that users are sometimes able to access sites that have been blocked, bypassing their internet searching rights.

From the logs, user accounts (e.g. 'domain\user') are blocked correctly but randomly their are computer accounts (e.g. 'domain\computer$') have also tried to authenticate with the server and have bypassed our rules. We don't store computer accounts in such a way, with appended dollar symbol, and seems to be very odd and intermittent.

Could anyone please shed any light on the situation? We run Windows 7 SP1 and Server 2008/2012 all on 64 bit versions.

Thanks.

Comment: You have disabled the ability to use local accounts on all your machines?

Comment: computer$ is a domain computer account, and you'll see that account used for connections made by system services, such as windows updates.

Comment: No, our users log in with their domain accounts but on occasions when we need to install specific software packages we use local accounts so they're not disabled.